# Unity Debug/Error No longer Says Line in Source Code

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ever since I upgraded my project and version of Unity from 5.6.0 to 5.6.1 the file and line in which the debug message or error occurred would not show up. This included double clicking the message, which wouldn't take me to the location of the error either.

Answer (score 1):

After suffering for weeks I found the answer to this problem while writing this post. **The solution is to expand the top right menu of the console tab, Stack Trace Logging > All and choose ScriptOnly.** This works for Visual Studio 17 and MonoDevelop.

Comment: That never happened to me while upgrading, but thanks for the info.